# Why shouldn't I use tabs for indentation?

Tags: ruby, indentation

In the Ruby community "everyone" is using spaces (mostly two spaces) for indentation. Since I prefer an indentation level of four spaces I use tabs instead. I think tabs are great because they let the editor show your preferred indentation level. Those who want to read my code with an indentation level of two spaces can easily do that without modifying the file.

But clearly I'm missing something obvious here, since nobody else is using tabs for indentation. For example, [these guidelines](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/rubyguide.shtml#indentation) recommends you to never use tabs, since they "include the practice of mixing tabs with spaces"(?) I can't remember that I have done that a single time in my whole life.

Does anyone else got better arguments for spaces? There has to be, since everyone is using them.

Comment: Since the question doesn't explicitly revolve around a programming problem but rather programming in general, we're going to scoot this question on over to our Programmers Q&A site. They'll be better able to answer ... and then debate about waffles and unicorns. Hope you're hungry...

Comment: Tabs and spaces are horrible when writing `make files`, but that has little to do with ruby :)

Comment: This is one of those "holy war" subjects in programming (right up there with vi vs emacs). There is no "right" answer to tabs vs spaces. In fact, those aren't even the only answers. For example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_tabstop

Comment: *"[tabs] let the editor show your preferred indentation level"* - I don't really know what you mean by that, but most decent code editors will happily deal with space-based indentation just as well as tabs.

Answer (score 3):

You need both tabs and spaces if you want to do something like this:

```
def foo:
    bar(some, long, argument, list,
        continued, on, another, line)
```

You can use a tab at the beginning of the "bar" line, and another at the beginning of the next line, but then it has to be followed by 4 spaces to make sure the arguments line up (if you used a tab, they would no longer line up with different tab widths). This works perfectly, but mixing tabs and spaces makes people afraid of introducing mixed indentation in the same file, and so often they decide to standardize on spaces alone.

Many editors will let you keep typing tab while inserting four spaces at onces, and handle backspaces as if you had typed a tab, so it works the way you're used to.

Comment: I see the problem, although I haven't encountered it myself. My editor makes the alignment for me, if a line is too long (unless I haven't broke it by myself, like you have done). I don't think four spaces and no tabs is an option, because then someone will be unhappy with the indentation level. Either I stay with tabs or I have to use two spaces, which I don't like.

Comment: @user544941: I think the point is that tabs show up as different sizes with different editors. So if you're trying to line up to the parenthesis on the third line, there's no guarantee that that will work on someone else's set-up.